Password authentication failed for user postgres supabase
I am trying to use Spring jdbc to connect to a supabase project that's self-hosted via docker and I'm getting the following error:
password authentication failed for user postgres supabase

My user is 'postgres' and password 'password'.
I tried setting it manually via postgres_admin (who has superuser privilages), setting it in .env, nothing seems to work.
It does work on a remote machine but not on my PC (both are freshly dowloaded docker images).
